# Angular 2.0 routing - TS 2305 ... has no exported member 'ModulewithProviders'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm following a **angular 2.0 tutorial** on angular js official [site](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html) and got stuck at the end of the routing excercise. The code worked last time but the other day when i hit '**npm start**' in the node.js cmd again, the "**error: TS 2305 ...  has no exported member 'ModulewithProviders**'" popped up despite the whole files left untouched.

Here's the code in the same app folder:

**main.ts:**

```
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AppModule} from './app.module';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {HeroesComponent} from './heroes.component';
import {DashboardComponent} from './dashboard.component';
import {routing} from './app.routing';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule,FormsModule,routing],
    declarations: [AppComponent, HeroesComponent, DashboardComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})

export class AppModule {}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <nav>
        <a routerLink="/heroes">Heroes</a>
        <a routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
        </nav>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `
})
export class AppComponent{
    title: string = "Tour of heroes"
}
```

**heroes.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'hero-component',
    template: `<div>Heroes </div>`
})
export class HeroComponent{};
```

**dashboard.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard-component',
    template: `<div>Dashboard </div>`
})
export class DashboardComponent{};
```

**app.routing.ts**

```
import { ModulewithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {HeroesComponent} from './heroes.component';
import {DashboardComponent} from './dashboard.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'heroes',
        component: HeroesComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }
]
export const routing: ModulewithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Answer (score 2):

`ModuleWithProviders` instead of `ModulewithProviders` ('W' instead of 'w').

You need to change it in both places in **app.routing.ts**

Comment: wow it worked, i doubted about that but how could it be :S? it worked even with ModulewithProviders. Anyway, thanks mate alot